# IFilterSample in 64bit Windows

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ifilter

Has anyone gotten the IFilter sample from Microsoft to work on 64bit Windows 7?  I am following the exact steps in the Readme.txt and I don't get the search to return the proper results.  Is there something I need to do to get this to work on 64bit windows that I am overlooking?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got my IFilter working on 64bit and 32bit by stopping and restarting the search system using.

```
NET STOP WSEARCH
<install your DLL>
NET START WSEARCH
```

I had thought this was a 32 bit/64bit problem, but it appears it was just the service not being restarted.